# Pandas series split then collapse

Tags: python, pandas

I have a split series as follows:

```
genes
0    A
1    B,C
2    D
genes.str.split(",")
0   [A]
1   [B, C]
2   [D]
```

This was created using a split. How do I then combine this into a singular Series?

```
genes
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another potential solution using [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

genes_stacked = pd.Series(np.hstack(genes.str.split(',')))
```

[out]

```
print(genes_stacked)

0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
s = genes.str.split(",", expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or list comprehension with flattening with `Series` constructor:

```
s = pd.Series([y for x in genes.str.split(",") for y in x])
```

Or [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
s = pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(genes.str.split(","))))
```

Comment: Slightly irrelevant, but do you know how to create the genes dataframe in the first place? When I do `df = pd.DataFrame({'genes': ['A', ['B', 'C'], 'D']})`, it gives me B,C in a list as expected, but how do I get the one like OP's original df, ie. not as list?

Comment: @amanb - use `pd.DataFrame({'genes': [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]})`

Comment: ok, that gives me the version after split is applied on the OP's dataframe. I was looking to achieve the one before the split. Not sure, if its possible to get it that way.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `pandas.Series` as an `iterable` in `str.join`, the `values` will be used.  Since it is that pesky comma that we want to eventually split on, we can first join with commas.

```
','.join(genes)

'A,B,C,D'
```

Which we can then easily split on those commas

```
','.join(genes).split(',')

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

It is then trivial to turn that into a `pandas.Series`

```
pd.Series(','.join(genes).split(','))

0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
dtype: object
```

---

#### Setup

```
genes = pd.Series(['A', 'B,C', 'D'])
```

Answer (score 1):

SO using `sum` after `split`

```
pd.Series(genes.str.split(",").sum())
Out[770]: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
dtype: object
```